# How to use Crystal Reports with parameters in PHP?

Tags: php, crystal-reports, odbc, sybase-asa

I would like to use Crystal reports with an ODBC (Sybase) data connection in PHP to display my database reports.

I selected Crystal Reports because of its advanced features, professional abilities, and its support for Sybase databases. I also found PHP Reports but it doesn't support Sybase.

My configuration is PHP v5, Sybase ASA 11, Crystal Reports 9, IIS 6.

I searched the web for practical examples and Applications and I tried them but they do not work.

Has anyone tried to do that before? Would you please provide me with such an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be no problem.  I have not done that exact sequence myself, but I have done many similar.

Ensure that you get ODBC working first (separate to Crystal & PHP).  Eg. Excel⇢ODBC⇢OpenClient⇢SybaseASE.  OpenClient comes on the CD.  ODBC is simple to set up: Datasource names, default db, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your interest and reply. I have made a crystal report and connect it to Sybase using ODBC. this is simple and no problems in it but when I try to include the code to call and open this report after putting it in my web root folder it fails. I read that the crystal report should be called as a Windows COM object and I set the COM object settings according to many examples I read on the net but no one works although I set it according to the settings I mention in my question post like Crystal Reports version.

Comment: @user493325, can you run the report successfully in the Crystal Reports Designer?

Comment: Yes, I can display it and run it in Crystal reports but i can not load it in PHP although I write the configuration code to load it. For example: I try the Code in that link .. http://p2p.wrox.com/php-databases/3598-crystal-reports-9-php.html
and like this link too http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/phpexperts/message/3231      plus other different codes and links but no example works with me !!

Comment: Dear ALL, I hope that anybody can help me and send the code needed to link PHP with Crystal Reports(V.9) as I described in my Question as I need that urgently. Thanks in Advance ..

Comment: @user493325: Caught your comment.  Sorry, I do not have expertise in that area.

Comment: Thanks for the Answers and the Comments although my problem still unsolved :( but I have not get new answers for it and I hope I can find good answers for my next questions :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the standard way it works but where I work we have a JSP that renders crystal reports.  To call it we use javascript to create a popup linked to the report renderer URL with the report location/parameters passed in the URL string.

If you don't want to use Tomcat then you could give i-Net Crystal Reports a go, that uses a java applet.

Comment: Thanks alot but which is better to use Crystal reports or Jasper reports in this way ?

Comment: It depends on whether or not you want to have Tomcat running to serve up the .jsp

Comment: I have no Tomcat as my web server is IIS version 6.0 and I am not sure if it is compatabile with Tomcat. Is it a necessary to run JSP ? Is that easy to integrate PHP with Java in the same web site ? Please provide an example or a reference for more details. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Tomcat is part of Apache, I'm not sure if you can get a jsp renderer for IIS, I have never really used jsp for anything besides this and I didn't implement it nor do we use it anymore.  The java viewer is part of the i-Net system service which monitors port 9000 so you create the report url in PHP so it looks like http://host:9000/?report=<location>&param1=<param1>...

Comment: May you send me a complete example and working application for that ? If it is ok sending me the reference you get from it will be more good. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't send you any of our code and I don't have time to write an example.

Comment: ok thanks for the answer and never mind but if you can send me a reference or a web link for it ..